# Using onClick directly in a DatePicker object instead of a DatePickerDialog connected to a button

Tags: android, onclick, datepicker

first let me say that I'm quite new to Android, so sorry if this question is really simple, but I couldn't find an answer for it in SO or Google.

I'm doing a small app for training and I I have this datePicker object:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:spinnersShown="true"
    android:onClick="selectDate" />
```

So, I've set up an onClick connection to a selectDate function I have:

```
public void selectDate(View view) {
    datePick = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    int yy = datePick.getYear();
    int mm = datePick.getMonth();
    int dd = datePick.getDayOfMonth();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(yy, mm, dd);
    int doy = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    populateDayOfYear(doy);
}
```

But the app doesn't do what is expected of it, and in fact after debuging, it never even enters this function.

So, just to be clear, what I want is to update a value (with the `doy` in the `populateDayOfYear(doy)`) of a EditText field every time I change a value in my datePicker, I **don't** want to press a button and be taken to a DatePickerDialog and only then be able to update the EditText field.

Is it possible with the standard datePicker or do I need to build one by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in OnCreate

```
datePick = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
datePick.init(2012,1,1,  new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener(){

   public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd){
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.set(yy, mm, dd);
      int doy = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
      populateDayOfYear(doy);
   }
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. This gives me an error tough: `Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener`. If I make it public it works tough, so please change that small thing and I can set your answer as the resolution to the problem.